# Pass Json Object and String Value at once in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to pass a Json Object and String Value together in ajax call. I have attached my code below.

```
$('#ddcountryid').change(function () {
            var jdata = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
            var Cid = $(this).val();
            //alert(intCountry);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropDown", "Pepmytrip")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: jdata,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirect) {
                        location.href = resolveUrl(data.url);

                    }
                    else {
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
                },

            });
        });
```

---

My Action Method

```
 public JsonResult PopulateDropDown(Wrapper wrapper, string cID)
        {
            wrapper.Destinations = new SelectList(context.Destinations.Where(c=>c.CountryId == cID), "id", "Name").ToList();
            return Json(wrapper);
        }
```

I am getting wrapper object with Values, but how can get the CID as well. Can anyone please help me on this??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it as query string parameter:

```
var Cid = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropDown", "Pepmytrip")' + '?cID=' + Cid, 
  ...
```

server side:

```
public JsonResult PopulateDropDown(Wrapper wrapper, string cID)
        {
            wrapper.Destinations = new SelectList(context.Destinations.Where(c=>c.CountryId == cID), "id", "Name").ToList();
            return Json(wrapper);
        }
```

**OR** add a new property to your Wrapper object as Gavin Fang suggested:

```
var Cid = $(this).val();
viewModel.Cid = Cid;
var jdata = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
```

server side code:

```
public JsonResult PopulateDropDown(Wrapper wrapper)
        {
            var cid = wrapper.Cid;
            wrapper.Destinations = new SelectList(context.Destinations.Where(c=>c.CountryId == cID), "id", "Name").ToList();
            return Json(wrapper);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a property to store you 'CID' to your viewModel.

and you can get the CID in the 'success' function in javascript in here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is two ways:

1. You can add extra field for existing json 'jdata' by defining field jdata.cid = null; and assigning it as jdata.cid = $(this).val();.
2. Prepare an object to hold both json data and string value:
   var obj = {"json": jdata, "string":$(this).value()};
   then pass obj in data parameter